# Same computer, mouse axis rotated 90 degrees no matter what OS is booted

Tags: windows-7, linux, usb, mouse, desktop-computer

My PC turned off suddenly due to blackout. When I turned it back on, the USB mouse axes were rotated 90 degrees to the right.

It's a dual boot (Windows/Linux) system, but no matter which one is booted, the same thing happens.

I tried a Windows 7 installer to see if it affected its GUI, and yes it did.

Ruling out any possible software cause, I'm completely clueless as to what caused this.

Comment: Have you tried a different mouse yet? Or a different USB port?

Comment: I'd like to have that mouse to keep kids away from my work computer

Answer (score 0):

Should've mentioned it was a wireless mouse. Fixed it by removing and returning the battery of the mouse.

At first I tried a wired USB mouse, plugged to the same port of the wireless mouse receiver, restarted, and axes still rotated. Tried different USB port for the wired mouse, mouse receiver plugged in its original place, restarted, same effect. Fortunately a PS/2 mouse was lying around, and tried that and everything was normal. Finally tried the battery thing on the wireless mouse and now it's ok. The unit is a Rapoo wireless mouse.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Are you ams342t0?  If so, it looks like you have created a second account, which will interfere with your ability to comment within your thread, edit your own posts, and accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged.